# Trying to have a user inputed string hold the value of a double variable

Tags: java, double, user-input

I am creating an project where when the user inputs a word, the word will have the value of an already existing double variable. How would I make the word be able to equal the double variable when the user types it in? After the user types the word in, the input will be put into another math equation.

```
double answer = 5.5;


  System.out.print("1st number: ");
                System.out.print("Enter first number: ");

                first = scanner.nextDouble();
// user inputs "Previous" , and the value is of the answer variable
                
                System.out.print("Enter second number: ");
                second = scanner.nextDouble();
// user inputs 1.1

                answer = first + second;
//5.5+1.1=6.6
```

Comment: When you say "word" do you actually mean "String"? Can you share the code you have so far?

Answer (score 0):

the only way to translate an input word into a double, would be to create a giant if clause that translates the different parts of for example "sevenhundredthousandnunhundredeightyone into 700981.
IF (!) you still want that, you can check use the subString Method and similar String methods to create conditions where the program can understand input numbers. But seriously, why bother?
this alone would be a real hassle and can be easily circumvented by having the user input a number.
you can then force the user to input a number by using a `try-catch` with a `NumberformatException`.
Just in case the user wants to mess with the program. Have him input a double or actually use an int, if you do not want to work with decimal places.
also do not forget to include a `if (a + b > Integer.MAX_VALUE)` clause `Integer.MIN_Value`. Does this help you?